# using unittest.skip with django-jenkins

Tags: django, jenkins, django-jenkins

I have added `@unittest.skip` decorator for few of my test methods. It works as expected while running with `python manage.py test --settings=PATH_TO_SETTING`

But it does not work with `python manage.py jenkins --settings=PATH_TO_SETTING`

I read that I need to add `JENKINS_TEST_RUNNER` to settings file but I am not aware of how to add that class.

How can I make it work with jenkins ?

Comment: what version of django-jenkins do you use?

Comment: Thanks for your time and response.


command `pip freeze | grep jenkins` is  showing `django-jenkins==0.16.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the JENKINS_TEST_RUNNER is not solving the problem.
it can be added as

```
 JENKINS_TEST_RUNNER = 'django_jenkins.runner.CITestSuiteRunner'
```

I solved the problem by setting the **name** attribute explicitly on the classes in whose test functions i am using unittest.skip